# Azure ServiceBus Retry Delay

Tags: azure, queue, servicebus

I am using the Microsoft Azure ServiceBus for Queue messages using WCF for the subscriptions. I am trying to implement retry logic. I use Peak/Lock to view the message and then have to do some local processing on the message. If that processing fails, I unlock the message so I can try processing it again. The problem is I need to build a have a delay in-between processing tries. Currently it is popped back into the queue and then is processed almost immediately. There needs to be about 2 minutes between attempts.

Answer (score 1):

If you always have to wait 2 minutes  before re-processing the message of that particular queue, you could try to configure the lock-timeout on the queue to be 2 minutes (plus the time you expect it will take you to process the message) and then just let the lock expire, instead of unlocking it. This has the downside that you would need to keep an eye on your processing time, and extend the lock's timeout if needed.

Another option could be to receive and complete the message, set a scheduled delivery of 2 minutes into the future, and re send the message. This has the downside that you need to consume it and ack it, which involves certain risks (e.g. your process dies before you get a chance to re-send the message).

Answer (score 0):

"If the message is Peeked in Peek Lock mode from a Queue then you don't have the receive context in the message. You can receive the message in Peek Lock mode, which will lock the message for the interval specified for the 'lock duration' property of the queue. Locked messages cannot be received until its lock expires. Thus, by setting the lock duration to 2 minutes and Receiving messages in Peek Lock mode will solve this issue.

You can either write custom code to update the Lock Duration property. Tools like Service Bus Explorer, Serverless360 etc provides options to update property using graphical user interface."